# Filesystem Watcher OnDelete Event fires

Tags: c#-4.0, filesystemwatcher

I have a FileSystemWatcher that monitors a folder for zip files and then performs an extraction of the files contents when added to the folder. All works well when copying or moving the files to the folder as expected. Chrome or IE browsers Save Target As or Save Link As hyperlinks download the file to the folder but the OnCreated event does not fire. Instead it fires OnDeleted when saving the zip file to the folder this way. The download hyperlink could be either web server based or local file to pc, neither which work. Is there a separate notify-filter that needs to be applied for this?

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false; // Hide form window.
        ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.

        if (!Directory.Exists(@"c:\fwbuilder"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\fwbuilder");
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(@"c:\fwbuilder\romdata"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\fwbuilder\romdata");
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher object.
        FileSystemWatcher fsWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        //listBox.Items.Add("Started FileSystemWatcher Service…");
        fsWatcher.Path = @"c:\fwbuilder";
        // Set Filter.
        fsWatcher.Filter = "*.zip";
        // Monitor files and subdirectories.
        fsWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        // Monitor all changes specified in the NotifyFilters.
        fsWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                                 NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                                 NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                                 NotifyFilters.FileName |
                                 NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                                 NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                 NotifyFilters.Security |
                                 NotifyFilters.Size;
        fsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        // Raise Event handlers.
        fsWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        fsWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        fsWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
        fsWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
        fsWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of downloading the file, have you tried to create file manually yet?

Comment: Yes, everything works correctly if the file is manually copied to the folder. Just doesn't work when using the save as link or target and downloading directly to the folder. Strange thing is I set a breakpoint on the OnCreated event handler and the first event to fire was it and I stepped through the function and

Comment: it did exactly as it was supposed to do. With no break point set, got my balloon popup the OnDelete event handler fired and it did not extract files as it was supposed to do. Windows 10, .Net 4.5 or browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what exactly is happening on the disk without seeing full details of file changes.

I suggest you do the following small experiment to better understand what happens when you download a file from browser and save it to the folder being watched by your program.

1. Remove *.zip filter from your watcher and watch all files
2. Write a log entry from all your event handlers along with timestamp and file name.
3. Run the program and save a file and observe the log.

It is likely that the browser is *creating* a temp file and renaming it to the desired name at the end of download. If this is indeed the case, you can start watching the rename operation and trigger your extract operation in there.

I guess you are missing the create event on the temp file because of .zip filter.

Try this and let me know how it goes. Also, post the result of the experiment (the log).

Comment: Indeed that is exactly what appears to be happening Sandeepa. Thank you for the troubleshooting tip. The file is renamed after the browser unlocks it. I had a using statement using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(e.FullPath)) that kept me from seeing the IoException error which showed when I changed it to a try{} catch{}. Any suggestions of how to test for a "file is being used by another process"? I've found several on the web and most say keep testing for when my application can successfully read the file to give it an all clear for me to do my extraction.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. 
For checking lock, I do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/snadahalli/9956952bbd15f184466f39210f0223c3)